# Checking Availability of user inputted File name

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input, os.path

My program requires the user to input a Filename for a text file.

It then needs to check if the file already exists.

```
 else:
        FileName = input("Please input a Valid File Name : ")
        if os.path.isfile("C:/Users/Brads/Documents/", FileName, ".txt"):
            print("File Exists")
        else:
            print("File does not exist")
```

However it errors like this every time and i have no clue why.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Brads/Python/5.py", line 108, in 
    FileName = input("Please input a Valid File Name : ")
    File "", line 1, in 
    NameError: name 'Test' is not defined
```

i have tried

```
+str(FileName)+
```

which also results in the same error.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `input` takes the user's input and attempts to `eval` it. You should use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead:

```
fileName = raw_input("Please input a valid file name: ")
# Here ----^
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, input() runs (`eval`s) the code as-is, so typing "Test" runs the code "Test", which since you haven't defined Test as a variable fails with a NameError.

Like kennytm says, in Python 2 you want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`; this saves the inputted text as a string instead of trying to run it. Your `str(FileName)` is too late, `eval` has already taken place and failed.

Or upgrade to Python 3, where `input` does what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Using python2 you would have to use raw_input and you would have to concatenate the path to form a string to avoid the error: *isfile() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)*

The code would look like this

```
FileName = raw_input("Please input a Valid File Name : ")
if os.path.isfile("C:/Users/Brads/Documents/" + FileName + ".txt"):
    print("File Exists")
else:
    print("File does not exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
import os
FileName = str(input("Please input a Valid File Name : "))
if os.path.isfile("C:/Users/Brads/Documents/{0}.txt".format(FileName)):
    print("File Exists")
else:
    print("File does not exist")
```

this way it's version compatible. Using .format is more neat than '+' or ','.